# Refreshing TEST site from Prod

Tags: move

I am trying to copy a site from PROD to TEST. (I had to remove http:// from the post so i can publish it here)

In Prod: 
teams.max.it/veri/desk and it's using Content_DB_42

I had DBA take a copy of the DB and move it to TEST DB

In TEST:
teams.max-test.it/veri/desk and it's using Content_DB_08

I tried the following but I get database already exists error
stsadm -o addcontentdb -url teams.max-test.it/veri/desk -databasename Content_DB_42 -databaseserver MAX_TEST_SQL

I tried move-spsite and i get following error

Move-SPSite teams.max-test.it/veri/desk -DestinationDatabase Content_DB_42

Move-SPSite : Site collection teams.max-test.it/veri/desk already exists in database Content_DB_42. Site collection will not be moved.

Finally, When I go to central admin for the TEST farm and I see that site still shows old database "Content_DB_08"

When I go to the test site it still has old data.

Comment: Have a look at site here https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f438ff74-10c7-4357-8173-54551d5e0375/movespsite-site-collection-already-exists-in-database?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Answer (score 0):

You've already tried creating a new site collection in the testing environment within the website teams.max-test.it/with name/desk, make sure to apply the same template that has the production site collection.
1. First copies the BD from the production server to tests from SQL server.
2. Atach the BD the main website in your case teams.max-test.it/, to accomplish this you run the next script:
Mount-SPContentDatabase "Content_DB_42" -DatabaseServer "name server data base" -WebApplication "http://teams.max-test.it/" -AssignNewDatabaseId 
3. By doing this you can now try the Move command again:
Move-SPSite http://ServerName/Sites/SiteName -DestinationDatabase

After this is finished, you restart the IIS and it should work.